# Looping multiple arrays with ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5UhR.jpg

I'm using the `ForEach` to iterate over an array of minerals in the example code, but I can't find a proper solution to loop the second array (mineral amount) right underneath the minerals.

In different project, I made it so far that the `ForEach` loops both arrays but for every mineral displays all amount for the `Planet` and for the second mineral all amount for the `Planet` and so on.

I did create a new struct with both arrays but without success. Adding a binding property also failed. I hope to learn a new swift method to achieve the desire look.

Data File

```
import Foundation

struct Planet: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var minerals: [String]
    var mineralAmount: [String]
}

let planetsData: [Planet] = [

Planet(name: "Jupiter", minerals: ["Iron", "Gold", "Copper"], mineralAmount: ["10K", "20K", "30K"]),
Planet(name: "Earth", minerals: ["Lithium", "Aluminium", "Quartz"], mineralAmount: ["40K", "50K", "60K"])
]
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var planet: Planet
    var body: some View {
    
      VStack() {
        ForEach(planet.minerals, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
                .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)

                        Text("amount to be added")
                            .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .regular))
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            ContentView(planet: planetsData[0])
        }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MDKs.png
```

Comment: Actually I haven't got the goal, you want to iterate over `planetsData` and then over `minerals` of each planet, right?

Comment: What do you mean by right underneath the minerals? Are you looking for two different lists on the same page, one for minerals and second for mineral amounts of a single planet? Can you provide some example about the final desired UI?

Comment: No. I want to iterate over minerals and then over mineral amount. A list showing "Iron" in large and right underneath "10K" in a small font.

Comment: @emreoktem just added a UI reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(0..<planet.minerals.count) { i in
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(planet.minerals[i])
                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    Text(planet.mineralAmount[i])
                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
            
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you create a  dictionary from both values

```
mineralsDic = [minerals: mineralAmount]
```

I of course know the syntax of `dictionary` but I just try to explain my idea + instead of making 2 loops you can make only one which has less complexity and better performance

Comment: This is the correct answer. By having two separate arrays, you have not associated an amount with a mineral. If you were to sort your mineral array at some point, the amount array would not match. By using a dictionary, you can key the amount by the mineral. You can use the dictionary keys as your items in the ForEach and return the amounts with the current iteration of keys.

Comment: yeah and you can make your array of keys and loop on it and print both value of key and value with O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: @Menaim SwiftUI beginner here Would the ContentView iterate over the mineralsDic in your case? could you provide some code for the solution?